# memory to cache mapping

Tags: c, caching, memory, mapping

We've just began the topic of cache, memory mapping, and address structure and I am confused on how to find the cache size for this question.

If a cache size is given to you as 128 blocks, and memory has 16kb block of 8 words each, where a word is 4 bytes, does it mean that each cache block is also 8 words each? Or does it mean that we have to divide 128 into 8 to get the actual number of cache blocks?  In that case what would the size of the cache be? Would it equal 128*8*4 in bytes?

Comment: What do you mean by *"memory has 16kb block"*?  In general, a cache is defined by 3 values - total cache size, cache line size, and cache associativity.  The only effect that main memory has on the cache is the minimum number of bits needed for the tag field.

Comment: I meant that the memory has a total of 16kb blocks. I thought that the size of memory would determine how many blocks would map to the same cache block?

Comment: That still doesn't make sense - "kb" and "block" are two separate units of size (the latter being a variable amount, but still a size unit). It's like saying a water bottle holds 1000mL ounces.  Either the memory has a total size of 16 kilobytes (probably [kibibytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibibyte) in reality) or a total size of 16k (16*1024) blocks (of some specific size, e.g. 8 words).  And in any case the size of memory does relate to how many possible addresses can map to a single cache line - this is directly related to the number of bits in the tag field.